# Swift AnyObject as? Set<T> crash

Tags: swift, generics, crash, foundation

I came across the following behaviour while programming in Swift:

If you run this snippet:

```
import Foundation

class A : Hashable, Equatable {

    var hashValue: Int {
        get { return ObjectIdentifier(self).hashValue }
    }

}

func ==(a:A, b:A) -> Bool {
    return a === b
}

typealias T = A
typealias TCollection = Array<T>

var element:TCollection = [T()]
var array:[AnyObject] = [element]

println(array[0] as? TCollection)
```

it prints:

```
Optional([SetCrashTest.A])
```

However if you change `TCollection` from `Array<T>` to `Set<T>`, it crashes with the following error:

```
Could not cast value of type 'SetCrashTest.A' (0x1001d1530) to 'NSObject' (0x7fff72a9d0f0).
```

Also, it runs correctly if I change `T` from `A` to some other type, like `Int`, `String`, `CGFloat` etc.
What causes this behaviour? And how can one do such optional downcasting without crashing?

**Edit:**
I experienced this crash when trying to read a `Set<T>` from an `NSNotification`'s `userInfo`, which is of type `[NSObject:AnyObject]`. It was only after this, that I've constructed the above example; so please don't advise to use `[TCollection]` instead of `[AnyObject]`, as `AnyObject` is dictated by the `NSNotification` API.

Comment: Interesting. Seems to work if A is derived from NSObject. I think it is worth filing a bug at https://developer.apple.com/bug-reporting/

Comment: Strangely it also works if I replace `as?` with `as!`.